# SeD regexp replacement

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I trying to do a really simple replacement in a config file with sed:
The line in the file is:

```
    local startday=os.time{year=2014, month=01, day=02, hour=00}
```

I want to read the year/month/day from a bash script and replace them in this file but not even the simplest sed command works. What I trying is:

```
sed -e '/day=/ s/=[0-9]{2}/=$DAY_FROMSCRIPT/' configfile
```

but interestingly if I specify:

```
sed -e '/day=/ s/=02/=$DAY_FROMSCRIPT/' configfile
```

That works. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: You need to escape curly braces: `{2}` should be `\{2\}`

Comment: Your `sed` dialect probably doesn't understand `{2}` repetition. Try `sed -r` or refactor to a BRE.

Answer (score 1):

Your original command has several mistakes:

- the curly braces have to be escaped `\{` or you have to use extended regular expressions (`-r` on Linux)
- you have to use `day=` in the regex, otherwise the replacement would match for `month=` too!
- you have to use double quotes so that the variable expansion `$DAY_FROMSCRIPT` works

Code:

```
sed "s/day=[0-9]\{2\}/day=$DAY_FROMSCRIPT/" configfile
```

If you want to replace also month and year, simply concat the sed commands in pipe:

```
sed "s/day=[0-9]\{2\}/day=$DAY_FROMSCRIPT/" configfile |
sed "s/month=[0-9]\{2\}/month=$MONTH_FROMSCRIPT/" |
sed "s/year=[0-9]\{2\}/year=$YEAR_FROMSCRIPT/"
```

Notes:

- sed `-e` option is not necessary
- the `/day=/` address part is also not necessary because you specify it in the sed `s` command

Answer (score 0):

To replace day, month, year:

```
sed -e "/startday=/ s/day=[0-9]\{2\}/day=$day/" \
    -e "/startday=/ s/month=[0-9]\{2\}/month=$month/" \
    -e "/startday=/ s/year=[0-9]\{4\}/year=$year/"
```

Your simple regex didn't work, because `sed` uses basic regular expressions (called [BRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_regular_expression)), where your have to write `{...}` as `\{...\}`.

If you're using GNU `sed`, you could enable extended regular expressions with the `-r` flag and write like this:

```
sed -r -e "/startday=/ s/day=[0-9]{2}/day=$day/" \
    -e "/startday=/ s/month=[0-9]{2}/month=$month/" \
    -e "/startday=/ s/year=[0-9]{4}/year=$year/"
```

In case of BSD `sed`, instead of `-r` flag you can use `-E` flag.

Another thing, I used `/startday=/` as the search pattern to be more strict. If that's unnecessary because you only have one line matching the patterns `day=`, `month=`, `year=` then you could omit the search pattern, like this:

```
sed -e "s/day=[0-9]\{2\}/day=$day/" \
    -e "s/month=[0-9]\{2\}/month=$month/" \
    -e "s/year=[0-9]\{4\}/year=$year/"
```

Comment: this will not work. There are much more mistakes in OPs script, see my answer.

Comment: @Tomas yeah I noticed. Thanks for pointing out, I fixed and improved now.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?:

```
sed -e 's/day=[0-9]\+/day='"$FROMSCRIPT"'/' \ 
    -e 's/month=[0-9]\+/month='"$FROMSCRIPT"'/' \ 
    -e 's/year=[0-9]\+/year='"$FROMSCRIPT"'/' \
configfile
```

You need to make sure, that the `$FROMSCRIPT` variables don't contain *problematic* content - such as the delimiter - which would break the `sed` pattern. As long as they contain numbers only it should be fine.

The regex condition in front of the `s/` command isn't necessary as you already specify that in your substitute regex. (Thanks to @Tomas for that catch)